# python3 __init__ qusetion : TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters

Tags: python-3.x

new to python
use python3.X
do not know how to solve

```
class Car():
        def __int__(self,make,model,year):
            self.make=make
            self.model=model
            self.year=year
    class ElectricCar(Car):
        def __init__(self,make,model,year):
            super().__init__(make,model,year)
    my_tesla =ElectricCar('tesla','model s',2016)

#TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

Comment: Once you fix your typo in the `Car` class (`__init__` instead of `__int__`) and your indentation, your code is valid for Python 3.2+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mispelled init in Car.init(). And it is `__init__()` not `init()` Try this:

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self,make,model,year):
        self.make=make
        self.model=model
        self.year=year
class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self,make,model,year):
        super().__init__(make,model,year)
my_tesla =ElectricCar('tesla','model s',2016)
```

Comment: TypeError: super() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: are you running on Python 2 or Python 3? if you were running on python2, you would change super() to super(ElectricCar,self). This code is running fine for me with Python 3